# Passing multiple data series to activity/service

Tags: android, android-activity

I know how to pass data from one activity to another using `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddTextNote.class);
intent.putExtra("text", note.text);
```

I'll ask my question with example: If one activity would pass only a string to another, the second activity will know that everytime it receives intent from the first activity, it contains only a string. But if the first activity passes multiple set of data on various occations to another, what is the best way to distinguish them? I mean let's say first activity will pass an integer if user presses button1, will pass an array of customClass if user presses button2 and will pas float if user presses button3. So briefly there is 3 ways to start the second activity.

How should I know what intent contains? I can check for being null, like:

```
string myStringParameter = intent.GetStringExtra("myStringParameter");
```

But it is a not a wise and efficient way. Is there anyway to distinguish them fast and effective?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that way could do the trick:

```
public enum State {
   BUTTON_1, BUTTON_2, BUTTON_3
}

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
  intent.putExtra("text", note.text);
  intent.putExtra("state", BUTTON_1); 
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
   State s = (State) intent.getSerializableExtra("state")
   switch (s) {
       case BUTTON_1:
           //get String value from intent and do what needed
           break;
       case BUTTON_2:
           //etc
           break;
       ....
   }
}
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: So you mean I should put extra byte/integer/enum for every intent that will be identifier of that intent, right?

Comment: It just normal practice. Technically there is many ways to that.

Answer (score 0):

Data is identified via strings.

Activity **A** sends:

```
intent.putExtra("stringA", ""+BUTTON_A);
intent.putExtra("stringB", ""+BUTTON_B);
```

Activity **B** receives:

```
String stringAdata = getIntent().getStringExtra("stringA");
String stringBdata = getIntent().getStringExtra("stringB");
```

Comment: Are you from PHP or JS ? )

Comment: In general it's possible to go that way, but quite ugly and irrational.